# Intercept keydown event on input element

Tags: reactjs, input, dom-events

I have a multipage form that is composed of `<input />` fields. Alongside the form I have a collection of "hotkeys" that are implemented via a custom hook (`window.attachEventListener("keydown", handler)` that listen for an `Alt + Key` combination. e.g. `Alt + N` will navigate to the next page of the form)

The issue I am having is that if the user has focus on an `<input />` and then attempts to fire the hotkey (`Alt + N`), the `<input />` is still receiving the `˜` character before triggering the hotkey.

I have tried to use capture mode, `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to no avail. Is there a way I can prevent the `<input />` elements in the form from receiving the `Alt + Key` keystroke?

**useHotkey hook**

```
export const useHotkey = (key: HotkeyTrigger, onTrigger: () => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTriggerKey = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.altKey && event.code === `Key${key}`) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // event.stopPropagation();
        // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        onTrigger();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleTriggerKey);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleTriggerKey);
    };
  }, [key, onTrigger]);
};
```

**EDIT: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-intercept-issue-qbvv7g?file=/src/App.tsx)**

Comment: Can you add a bit of input code that can help in reproducing this issue?

Comment: @poo Added a codesandbox link

Comment: I have tried the codesandbox you've linked and nothing is sent to the input by the `Alt+n` combination. It seems to work fine. Tested in Firefox and Chrome on Mac and win 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround for you, remove the focus from the input when you use the hotKeys.

```
export const useHotkey = (
  key: string,
  onTrigger: () => void,
  document: any // Add this parameter 
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTriggerKey = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.altKey && event.code === `Key${key}`) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].blur();//Add this line
        onTrigger();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleTriggerKey);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleTriggerKey);
    };
  }, [key, onTrigger]);
};
```

and the call your function as follows:

```
useHotkey("N", () => console.log("Triggered"), document);
```

I hope this should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: This works great, thank you!
I needed to adjust it to blur all inputs, since the index of the input that is focussed would be unknown, so I ended up with the following:

[...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].forEach((input) => input.blur());